# NLA editor gets tangled all up in Blender 2.75?

Tags: animation, nla-editor

Don't know what to do with this mess. [image]
Plane.002 is just a still object in my scene. Don't know how It got an action strip.
I want to clean up NLA editor and action editor up by removing four actions indicated below. I tried to delete some of the action strips to remove the actions but other action got messed up.
Not quite understand the NLA editor yet. I'd like some one to clean up NLA and action editor for me and show me how the NLA editor works!
Thanks!

Blend file:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NLA editor is complex I strongly recommend read the documentation. I will show how I cleanup the references to an action.

[Blender NLA Doc](https://blender.org/manual/animation/editors/nla.html)

First you need to clean up the reference by deleting the tracks (start icon), select the  Plane.002 ActionStrip and the NlaTrack Action and press X to delete it (be sure to only select the ActionStrip and the NLATrack), Repeat the process for Plane.001 and Plane ActionStrip

[image]

Next select the ActionStrip Plane.002 and delete the Action by hold Shift+(press the icon) X. This will delete the reference to the Action. Repeat the same for Plane.001 and Plane ActionStrip

[image]

Note how Blender will warning you about the 0 references and that the Action will not be saved at the top most bar (or status bar near the windows title)

[image]

Finally save and re-open the file:

[image]

I can only summarize that you can save an Action an apply that Action to another object Note how I apply Skate -> Skate.001Action ActionStrip to Plane.002 object. The number 2 next to the action indicate that the ActionStrip have two references. the NLA does a lot more things.

[image]